# Using .values.max() for arrays

Tags: python, pandas

I use the following code to get a row from a dataframe and then find the max value.

```
def find_max(a):
    return a.values.max()

row = df.iloc[0].astype(int)
max_value = find_max(a)
```

That works fine. However, if I pass an array like

```
ar = [1,2,3]
max_value = find_max(ar)
```

it doesn't work and I receive `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'`. How can I use that function for both types?

Comment: something along the lines of `isinstance dataframe else max()`?

Comment: Note: a Python `list` is *not generally referred to as an array*. Pandas builds on top of numpy, which does have array type. You could use `numpy.max()`, and test if `.values` exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def find_max(a):
    if isinstance(a, list):
        return max(a)
    elif isinstance(a, pd.DataFrame):
        return a.values.max()
    else:
        print("No max method found for the input type")
```

Comment: I assumed that DataFrame is the default input type. How would you improve it?

Comment: Its fine hence the edit and upvote - try: except: would work for any sequence but it is not needed

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thanks. How does a try-except block compare to my current (edited) solution? Would that be better?

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to test for the type, or use exception handling, to switch approaches:

```
def find_max(a):
    if isinstance(a, list):
        return max(list)
    return a.values.max()
```

or

```
def find_max(a):
    try:
        return a.values.max()
    except AttributeError:
        # assume a Python sequence
        return max(a)
```

Which one you pick depends on a few factors:

- Do you need to support other iterables, like tuples or sets or generators?
- What is the more common case; the `try...except` case is faster if the majority of calls pass in a Pandas series.

Another option is to use `np.max()`, which works on either type:

```
import numpy as np

def find_max(a):
    return np.max(a)
```

Note that there is no need to use the `.values` attribute here!

Comment: I would have actually checked for a dataframe type instead of a list, as max "covers" everything but that, but I like the EAFP approach better anyway

Comment: @Bharel: it depends. What other types are you passing in?

Comment: I'm not the OP, but considering `.values.max()` will work only for specific types while `max` is for general iterables, I'd special case the first.

Comment: @Bharel: I meant the general 'you' more than the specific. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Why don't try [numpy's integration](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html?) for that?

```
import numpy as np

row = df.iloc[0].astype(int)
max_value = np.max(a.values)

ar = [1,2,3]
max_value = np.max(ar)
```

This way, you don't have to define a function. In general it`s more pythonic to use already existing and well tested functionality from python packages.